# Implementing Spin lock vs. Win32 Critical section

Tags: winapi, critical-section, spinlock

I'm trying to optimize Win32's CRITICAL_SECTION for more "complex" synchronization primitives, where I don't need the reentrance feature of the critical section. So here's my spin lock so far:

```
class MSpinLock
{
    volatile LONG X;
public:
    
    void Enter()
    {
        while (1)
        {
            const LONG ret = ::InterlockedExchange(&X, 1);
            if (X == 1 && ret == 0) break;

            MBOOL shouldsleep = 1;
            for (int iter=0; iter<1024; iter++)
            {
                _mm_pause();
                if (X == 0) { shouldsleep = 0; break; };
            };
            if (shouldsleep) ::SwitchToThread();
        };
    };

    //void Exit() { ::InterlockedExchange(&X, 0); };
    void Exit() { X = 0; };
};
```

The first question is whether the Exit implementation is sufficient like this?

And mainly I started comparing it to critical sections by allocating multiple threads which do something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++)
{
    TheLock.Enter();
    DummyVariable++;
    TheLock.Exit();
};
```

Then just waiting for the threads. It's not exactly scientific test, but does the trick for now apparently - with just a single thread, the threads finish 3x faster compare to using the critical section. But once there are more threads it gets way worse. So apparently when there are concurrent threads, the algorithm starts spending too much time somewhere in the loop, or perhaps the fairness is just too bad. Any ideas how to optimize this?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* - Not the kind of question you should be asking on Stack Overflow (see [ask]). *"the algorithm"* - What algorithm are you trying to implement? Also note that Windows XP introduced [`InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsectionandspincount). Did you try that? It allows you to control the spin count until a thread gives up acquiring a critical section.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks, the thing is, critical sections are naturally reentrant, which I suspect may lower the performance. So I'm trying to implement something more simple and faster.

Comment: How do you (or we) know *"something is faster"* (or slower) when you do not establish a baseline implementation you're comparing against? What you've shown is essentially what `InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount` does. You aren't going to gain much performance here. The costly part is calling into the kernel. Please prepare a use case so that we know what you're trying to optimize.

Comment: The `Exit` is not sufficient because the memory order of the store to `X` is unspecified, and it may propagate to other processors before the update to `DummyVariable`. If you're looking for something lighter than a critical section, consider an SRWLock.

Comment: If you don't need the full power of a `CRITICAL_SECTION` then consider using a [Slim Read/Write Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks) instead (oh, I didn't notice Raymond already suggested that!).